# HtmlUnit ScriptException errors

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I am using HtmlUnitDriver,& here is my code.

```
   HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
   driver.get("some url here");
```

I am getting following Exception:

```
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement (http://sales.liveperson.net/hcp/html/mTag.js?site=7824460#1(eval)#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:595)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:545)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:896)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:162)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:221)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:735)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement$2.run(HtmlElement.java:866)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:537)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:538)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.fireEvent(HtmlElement.java:871)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1162)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:202)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:440)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:346)
    ... 8 more
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Put little more code , and what actually you are putting as URL.

Comment: It's most likely the string isn't formatted correctly. It sounds like it wants a specific format and not just a URL.

Comment: Well it looks like that's complaining about the Javascript, not the Java code... what does your Javascript look like?

Comment: Can you post some more code, as exception says you have missed `a semi-colon` somewhere... We want to see that "Somewhere"..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many questions are asked referencing this kind of issues. The `ScriptException` is raised because you have a syntactical error in your javascript. Most browsers manage to interpret the JS even with some kind of errors but HtmlUnit is a bit inflexible in that sense.

Your options are:

1. Correct JS code
2. Disable JS in the `WebClient`
3. Don't use HtmlUnit. Use a different framework with better JS support such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (note it is not a Java-based framework)

Answer (score 6):

```
_webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

works in this incorrect JS scenario.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error with the liveperson mTag.js

The problem is with the compacted mTag.js response.

There are several workaround:

1. Replace the compacted mTag.js with a clear one (requires LivePerson support)
2. Work with a 'real' Selenium WebDriver (Firefox Driver or similar)