# HtmlUnit not creating HtmlPage object

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, htmlunit, headless-browser

I'm very new to HtmlUnit and I'm trying to scrape a website that uses Javascript to edit the code. I heard [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) was the best way to go as it returns the **final** code using a headless browser.

However as you will see I cannot even get past creating a HtmlPage object without getting a huge and impossible to understand exception thrown (at least given my virtually null experience with HtmlUnit).

Here is my code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main scraper = new Main();
        scraper.testingGargoyle();


    }

    private void testingGargoyle() {
        String myUrl = "https://www.wearvr.com/#game_id=game_4";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        try {
            HtmlPage myPage = ((HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(myUrl));
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the exception that gets thrown :

```
Apr 30, 2015 5:43:50 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Apr 30, 2015 5:43:50 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[https://load.sumome.com/] line=[1] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[19] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object function (e, n, r) {...}. (https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js#19)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object function (e, n, r) {...}. (https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js#19)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:847)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:733)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1096)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:395)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:270)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:793)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:751)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1017)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:248)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:194)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:471)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:345)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:410)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:395)
    at Main.testingGargoyle(Main.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object function (e, n, r) {...}. (https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js#19)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3714)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:724)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:832)
    ... 31 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function bind in object function (e, n, r) {...}. (https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js#19)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3629)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3613)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3634)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3714)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2233)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2215)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1333)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:19)
    at script.r(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:16)
    at script.r(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:384)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:16)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:16)
    at script.t(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:16)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:16)
    at script.t(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:7)
    at script.t(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:463)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:463)
    at script.t(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script.t(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at script(https://www.wearvr.com/assets/scripts/bundle.b4038a088bb1abfcf55c.js:1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:724)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:832)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:733)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1096)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:395)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:270)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:793)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:751)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1017)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:248)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:194)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:471)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:345)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:410)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:395)
    at Main.testingGargoyle(Main.java:19)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

I told you it was huge. How can I get around this and obtain the final source of this page in order to get scraping?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exceptions are thrown for several reasons, wrong html, errors on script's page, resources not found such css, script files or images files (for example `<img src="bla.gif"> <- bla.gif not found HTML404)`

So we use those options to keep html navegating without stoping on first error/problem we use :

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
```

You can also implement empty classes to stop htmlUnity go verbose on console about css/javaScript errors with:

```
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());    
webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new JavaScriptErrorListener(){});
```

The little sample test case:

```
@Test
public void TestCall() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {      
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true); //ignore ssl certificate
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    String url = "https://www.wearvr.com/#game_id=game_4";
    HtmlPage myPage = webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(200);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
    //do stuff on page ex: myPage.getElementById("main")
    //myPage.asXml() <- tags and elements
    System.out.println(myPage.asText());

}
```

Comment: I didn't explain comands `  webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(200);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);`

Comment: This is awesome stuff man! Given the length of the exception I thought this was hopeless but man thank you!

Comment: webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a different browser, e.g.:

```
String myUrl = "https://www.wearvr.com/#game_id=game_4";
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
    HtmlPage myPage = ((HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(myUrl));
    System.out.println(myPage.asXml());
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, it could also be a bug in IE8 simulation

Comment: Yes, with latest snapshot