# Selenium HTMLUnitDriver Anchor tag click event not working

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver

I am working on scraping some data from site using selenium html unit driver but when i click on Anchor tag using click() function i got below exception

`net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function getOwnPropertySymbols in object function Object() {
    [native code]
}. (https://ptscsccpro.clouda.sat.gob.mx/Scripts/SubContratacion/3rdparty/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js?v2.0.2#650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:2053)`

I don't know why this exception occur.

My Anchor tag html code is like,

```
<a id="textId" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="function('url'); return false;">TEXTTEXT</a>
```

I tried by below many ways ,

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("textId"));
link.click();


((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "arguments[0].click();", link);


((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("jQuery(\"a[id='textId']\").trigger('mouseover').trigger('click');")
```

but always i am failed.
So,how can i working using click() function?
Anyone know..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774746/htmlunit-exception

Comment: @kushal this link is different exception compare to this exception

Comment: try following: `WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("textId")); new Action(driver).moveToElement(link ).click().build().perform();`